# Using reusable models and injecting these where required in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Anyone know the best recommended way of creating models in a separate JavaScript file and have these injected into the controllers that need them, rather than creating the models on fly normally in the controller?

This would make it so much easier to pass around the model and you would know exactly what you was passing around.

I have some thoughts on using Services, and inject these where I need i.e. controllers.

Controllers would then pass these onto specific services to do any heavy lifting to keep my controllers nice and light.

Is services the only and recommended way to go ?  Or is there a better alternative way ?

Any use of third-party libraries / modules would also be considered.

Comment: Would using scope inheritance work for you? I.e. an innermost controller has access to all its parents scopes.

Answer (score 1):

I think services are the way to go. Not only are they injectable but they are also Singletons - meaning wherever they are injected, the same instance is shared.

Example of a service which uses the $http service to make an asynchronous call to retrieve data:

```
app.factory('customerService', function($http)  {
   var customers = [];
   $http({ url: 'api/customers/all', method:'GET'}).success(function(data) {
       angular.copy(data, customers);
   });
   return {
      customers: customers
   };
});
```

In your controller or directive, you can then inject the service and bind customers to your scope:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, customerService) {
     $scope.customers = customerService.customers;
});
```

Comment: Yep, but anyway to inject a new instance into a controller ? or to reset the values in the service to its default ?

Comment: Services are always singletons. If you really want to reset it, then expose a getNewInstance() method from your service, or resetInstance(instance) to reset it once you have one.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is by service for couple of reasons.

- If you use ng-view and routing the service is not reloading and your data is safe in service
- It's easy injectable to controllers
- Provides two-way data binding between controllers

working plunker with two-way data binding between controllers
http://plnkr.co/edit/pt2xwlYqvY3r840tHJ92?p=preview

NOTE: if you don't have a dot in your model you are doing something wrong ;)

Comment: Agreed, thats the lines i was thinking, but how to reset a service ? :-) How to reset a service to its original values? Anyway of doing this or its a case of creating my own method to clear out the service. Is there anyway a service can be created as a non singleton, just out of interest, so i could have 2 instances of service xyz?

Comment: To reset service you will indeed need to create your own method. Its not really possible to have 2 instances of the same service, but if you don't care about two-way data binding you could use setters/getters and return different object depending on parameter send to service (hope that makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

I believe services are the best way for this.

I have used scope inheritance to place some methods that most of my app would need at once such as a routing method I attached these to the .run () method of my main module/app.

You could separate your models into separate modules if you needed to structure your app that way.